# Kill or interrupt a running script on OS X (PyCharm)

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, interrupt

I have a problem with using PyCharm on OS X. I decided to run a for loop in my script (I selected the bit of the script that I need, right click, and then Execute Selection in Console), and I realised that the for loop is insanely inefficient and takes way too long. So I would like to kill the running process, simply interrupt it.

PyCharm tells me to press Ctrl+C in console to interrupt, but I keep pressing it, as well as Command+C, nothing happens. I tried to interrupt it in the terminal as well, with no success.

Does anybody know a way around? I know I can just close it but then I lose all my existing variables and dataframes that I ran previously...

Comment: are you `try/except`ing `KeyboardInterrupt` anywhere?

Comment: Side note: you may find the `signal` module useful, which allows you to set an alarm to kill a task after x seconds in case something runs too long.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by try/excepting KeyboardInterrupt?

Comment: does your code (or referenced code) use `KeyboardInterrupt` anywhere?

Comment: No, it does not.